# COM - return an array of object interfaces

Tags: com, idl

I want to return from IDL an array of interfaces.
I try this:

```
interface ISecurityPolicy : IDispatch{
[id(6)]          HRESULT GetPolicyList([out, ref, retval] SAFEARRAY(IEntityPolicy*)* result);
}
```

I get this warning(in VS 2010):
Warning 1   warning MIDL2456: SAFEARRAY(interface pointer) doesn't work using midl generated proxy : [ Parameter 'result' of Procedure 'GetPolicyList' ( Interface 'ISecurityPolicy' ) ]

Is this a bogus warning as http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcmfcatl/thread/84a632a9-4e29-4a95-8da7-f7aedb650339 might suggest ?

Comment: Drop the [ref] attribute, it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I'm afraid that I still get the warning for that too. On the other side, things work, you just have to adjust the return type as  SAFEARRAY(IUnknown*)* to make things easier

Comment: It could be a better idea for me to use a collection implementation for the same propose though. It would be much more clear, only more work to do :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring this as:

```
interface ISecurityPolicy : IDispatch{
[id(6)]          HRESULT GetPolicyList([out, ref, retval] SAFEARRAY(IUnknown*)* result);
}
```

simplifies things a little for implementation of the interface.
It could still be a better idea though instead of returning an array of interfaces to the caller to return it an iterator over the "collection".